# How to undo a commit in freshly initialized repository (not pushed)

Tags: git

I intialized a repo but now want to [undo](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/2845731/how-to-uncommit-my-last-commit-in-git) the **first** (and only) commit.

These [three solutions](https://stackoverflow.com/a/2846154/5783745) for undoing a commit all error because the [freshly created repo points to a ref that doesn't exist yet](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/12267912/git-fatal-ambiguous-argument-head-unknown-revision-or-path-not-in-the-workin)

So my question is how do I undo a commit in a repo that hasn't been pushed and hence hasn't got a ref yet?

Note: I have also tried `git commit -amend` without success

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Note: technically this doesn't *undo* the commit, but it's just as good—an empty repository has little function.  To really empty out the repository, see below.

`git commit --amend` should work.  Here is a demonstration:

```
$ git init
Initialized empty Git repository in .../.git/
$ echo test changing root commit > README
$ git add README 
$ git commit -m initial
[master (root-commit) 90e83ae] initial
 1 file changed, 1 insertion(+)
 create mode 100644 README
$ echo different readme > README
$ git add README 
$ git commit --amend --no-edit
[master 8e159b1] initial
 Date: Sat Mar 2 21:00:53 2019 -0800
 1 file changed, 1 insertion(+)
 create mode 100644 README
$ git log --all --decorate --oneline --graph
* 8e159b1 (HEAD -> master) initial
```

Note that the "different README" is what went in to this new root commit:

```
$ git show --pretty=oneline
8e159b1f0d397b31cb1be5168e77ba200269c62a (HEAD -> master) initial
diff --git a/README b/README
new file mode 100644
index 0000000..ef0411a
--- /dev/null
+++ b/README
@@ -0,0 +1 @@
+different readme
```

If you have files you don't want in the new root commit, use `git rm` (perhaps with `--cached`) to remove them.

---

If you really want to delete the `master` branch and its single commit, and then be on the `master` branch as you normally are in a new, empty repository, it takes a couple of extra steps, at least as long as you want to use normal (not plumbing) commands.  Here are the steps:

1. `git branch -m master delete`: rename the `master` branch out of the way
2. `git checkout --orphan master`: get back on a branch named `master` that does not exist
3. `git branch -D delete`: delete the unwanted branch
4. `git read-tree --empty`: empty out the current index

The work-tree is undisturbed by this process.

Answer (score 1):

If you have just one commit you want to remove, you can just remove the `.git/logs/refs/heads/master` file that recorded the commit log ID.  Also remove file `.git/refs/heads/master` that recorded the commit for the `master` branch.
You may also want to remove the `.git/logs/HEAD` file that stores the last commit ID.
After removing those references the objects will eventually garbage-collected.

But probably it's easier and faster to remove the whole `.git` directory and `git init` again.