# Always losing git history when switching PCs

Tags: git, git-log, data-loss, data-corruption

I am using a SATA SSD that I always keep on myself and that I'm storing all my projects on.
Recently though, I started losing data when plugging the SSD into a PC after being plugged into another one (most files ended up being nothing but this character, repeated x times: �)
Both devices run Windows 10.
If this happens, I can plug the SSD out and back in, resulting in the data being restored.
But after I do this, all files in my workspace suddenly end up being unstaged and if I try to open the git log with the VS Code extension [Git History](https://github.com/DonJayamanne/gitHistoryVSCode) (v0.4.6), this is git's output:

```
git rev-parse --show-toplevel
git rev-parse --show-toplevel
git rev-parse --show-toplevel
git rev-parse --show-toplevel
git rev-parse --show-toplevel
git rev-parse --show-toplevel
git rev-parse --show-toplevel
git rev-parse --show-toplevel
git rev-parse --show-toplevel
fatal: ambiguous argument 'HEAD': unknown revision or path not in the working tree.
```

This basically always means I have to delete the `.git` folder and having to `git init` again, resulting in all my progress being lost.
I've also tried doing the things in the answers of [this Stackoverflow question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/12267912/git-fatal-ambiguous-argument-head-unknown-revision-or-path-not-in-the-workin) but that also just clears the history and I lose all progress.
This is really, really frustrating and I don't know what the exact issue is.
The git login information is the exact same on both PCs.
SSD hot-swapping is enabled on both PCs and I always make sure to use the Windows thing to remove the external drive securely or wait until the PC is shut down completely but still this keeps happening.