# Git 2.34.1: error "fatal: ambiguous argument 'HEAD': unknown" when committing in bash with no profile loaded

Tags: bash, git

```
$ bash --noprofile                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                  

The default interactive shell is now zsh.
To update your account to use zsh, please run `chsh -s /bin/zsh`.
For more details, please visit https://support.apple.com/kb/HT208050.

bash-3.2$ git --version
git version 2.34.1


bash-3.2$ git status
On branch master

No commits yet

Changes to be committed:
  (use "git rm --cached <file>..." to unstage)
    new file:   readme.md

Untracked files:
  (use "git add <file>..." to include in what will be committed)
    tmp/

bash-3.2$ git commit -m 'initial'
fatal: ambiguous argument 'HEAD': unknown revision or path not in the working tree.
Use '--' to separate paths from revisions, like this:
'git <command> [<revision>...] -- [<file>...]'

bash-3.2$ which omz # checking for oh-my-zsh

bash-3.2$ git rev-parse # no errors, so that's not it 

bash-3.2$
```

I've been knocking my head against this one for a bit now so it's time to ask for help.

Git was working fine until yesterday, but I haven't done a commit in an empty repo for a few weeks. Tried upgrading `git`. I get the same error with/without `zsh` and `oh-my-zsh`. [This similar question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/12267912/git-error-fatal-ambiguous-argument-head-unknown-revision-or-path-not-in-the), well the top answer is about 9 years old and didn't help. Commit with `--allow-empty` caused the same error. The other answers in there didn't help either.

OSX 10.15.7

Comment: I suspect there's a git hook that's firing and running some command? maybe take a look at `.git/hooks/*` (most likely `.git/hooks/pre-commit`)

Comment: Nothing there, but it might be in a global hook, checking now

Comment: `git config core.hooksPath` might be helpful for finding that then

Comment: yep that was it, go ahead and make an answer and I'll add the solution to your answer

Answer (score 2, accepted):

it sounds like a faulty git hook is firing which is referencing `git diff HEAD` or some sort (probably instead meaning to use `git diff --staged --name-only`)

make sure to check `.git/hooks/*` (probably `.git/hooks/pre-commit`) or if you've configured a global hook path also check the value of `git config core.hooksPath`

Get your hooks path:

`git config --global core.hooksPath`

Check for `git rev-parse` in any of the hooks there, especially `prepare-commit-msg`.

Comment: in my case a `prepare-commit-msg` script was running `git rev-parse --abbrev-ref HEAD` to check for commits to master. I changed it to `git branch --show-current`.

Comment: and thanks for the assist 